# Red Black Tree outputting strange order

Tags: tree, red-black-tree

For my class I've been asked to write a red black tree program that reads in an existing tree then performs insertions. I've gotten it to read in the tree correctly, the first few insertions restructure correctly, but after about the 2nd or 3rd input the out of the order of the tree does not match the professors. I've combed over my code a thousand times and compared against psuedocode and c++ implementation from all over. I simply cannot find the error.

I would appreciate any help I can get here. I'm not asking any one to do my homework for me, I have it all done, I'm just getting a slightly different output. I've included the testcase input, the professors output and my own output. I've also include all the code.

**Test Case Input file**

```
8
1 11
0 2
1 1
1 7
0 5
0 8
1 14
0 15
7
4
9
300
19
321
500
18
```

The first line is the number of elements in the existing tree. 0 for red 1 for black. After the tree there is an integer (7 in this case) that indicates how many elements to insert.

**Professor's Output**

```
1 7
0 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
0 11
1 8
1 14
0 15

1 7
0 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
0 11
1 8
0 9
1 14
0 15

1 7
0 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
0 11
1 8
0 9
1 15
0 14
0 300

1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 11
1 8
0 9
0 15
1 14
1 300
0 19

1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 11
1 8
0 9
0 15
1 14
1 300
0 19
0 321

1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 15
0 11
1 8
0 9
1 14
0 300
1 19
1 321
0 500

1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 15
0 11
1 8
0 9
1 14
0 300
1 19
0 18
1 321
0 500
```

**My output**

```
1 7
0 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
0 11
1 8
1 14
0 15


1 7
0 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
0 11
1 8
0 9
1 14
0 15


1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 11
1 8
0 9
0 14
1 15
0 300


1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 11
1 8
0 9
0 14
1 19
0 15
0 300


1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 14
0 11
1 8
0 9
0 19
1 15
1 300
0 321


1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 14
0 11
1 8
0 9
0 19
1 15
1 321
0 300
0 500


1 7
1 2
1 1
1 5
0 4
1 14
0 11
1 8
0 9
0 19
1 15
0 18
1 321
0 300
0 500
```

**Makefile**

```
run: main.o RBnode.o RBnode.h RBTree.o RBTree.h
    g++ -g3 -ggdb -O0 main.o RBnode.o RBTree.o -o RBtree

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm -f RBtree *.o core core.*

tidy: clean
    rm -f *.*~ *~
```

**RBTree.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include"RBTree.h"
#include<cstdlib>

// Set up tree
RBtree::RBtree(){


        nil = new RBnode();
        root = nil;

}

RBtree::~RBtree(){

}

// Writes pre-order tree starting at root node to file FD
void RBtree::RBwrite(RBnode* tempRoot, FILE * fd){

        if(tempRoot != nil){

    fprintf(fd,"%d %d\n", tempRoot->colorData, tempRoot->data);

    RBwrite(tempRoot->lchild,fd);
        RBwrite(tempRoot->rchild,fd);

        }

}


// Returns root node of tree
RBnode* RBtree::getRoot(){

        return root;
}

// Insertion for a new node
RBnode* RBtree::RBinsert(int data){

        RBnode* x;
        RBnode* y;

        RBnode* z = new RBnode();
        z->data = data;


        y = this->nil;
        x = this->root;

        while(x != nil)
        {
                y = x;
                if(z->data < x->data)
                        x = x->lchild;
                else
                        x = x->rchild;
        }

        z->parent = y;
        if(y == nil)
            {    root = z;}
                //Empty Tree
        else if(z->data < y->data)
           {     y->lchild = z;}
        else
               { y->rchild = z;}
        z->lchild = nil;
        z->rchild = nil;
        z->changeColor(0);

 return z;

}





// Insertion of existing value from an existing tree
RBnode* RBtree::RBinsert(int color, int data){

        RBnode* z = new RBnode();
        z->changeColor(color);
        z->changeData(data);

        RBnode* x = root;
        RBnode* y = nil;
    while(x != nil)
    {
        y = x;
        if(z->data < x->data)
            x = x->lchild;
        else
            x = x->rchild;
    }
    z->parent = y;
    if(y == nil)
        root = z; //empty as Fword
    else if(z->data < y->data)
       { y->lchild = z;}
    else
       { y->rchild = z;}
    z->lchild = nil;
    z->rchild = nil;

return z;
}


// Fixup function. Based off algorithm from CLRS 
void RBtree::RBinstertFixup(RBnode* z){

        RBnode* y;

while(z->parent->colorData == 0 && z->parent != nil) {

        if(z->parent == z->parent->parent->lchild)
        {
                y = z->parent->parent->rchild;
                if(y->colorData == 0)
                {
                        z->parent->changeColor(1);
                        y->changeColor(1);
                        z->parent->parent->changeColor(0);
                        z = z->parent->parent;
                }
                else
                {
                        if(z == z->parent->rchild)
                        {
                                z = z->parent;
                                Lrotate(z);
                        }
                z->parent->changeColor(1);
                z->parent->parent->changeColor(0);
                Rrotate(z->parent->parent);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                y = z->parent->parent->lchild;
                if(y->colorData == 0)
                {
                        z->parent->changeColor(1);
                        y->changeColor(1);
                        z->parent->parent->changeColor(0);
                        z = z->parent->parent;
                }
                 else
                {
                        if(z == z->parent->lchild)
                        {
                                z = z->parent;
                                Rrotate(z);
                        }
                z->parent->changeColor(1);
                z->parent->parent->changeColor(0);
                Lrotate(z->parent->parent);
                }
        }
}
    root->changeColor(1);
}


// Left rotate
void RBtree::Lrotate(RBnode* x) {

        RBnode* y;

        y = x->rchild;
        x->rchild = y->lchild;
        if(y->lchild != nil)
                y->lchild->parent = x;
        y->parent = x->parent;
        if(x->parent == nil)
                root = y;
        else if(x == x->parent->lchild)
                x->parent->lchild = y;
        else
                x->parent->rchild = y;

        y->lchild = x;
        x->parent = y;
}


// right rotate
void RBtree::Rrotate(RBnode* x) {

        RBnode* y;

        y = x->lchild;
        x->lchild = y->rchild;
        if(y->rchild != nil)
                y->rchild->parent = x;
         y->parent = x->parent;
        if(x->parent == nil)
                root = y;
        else if(x == x->parent->lchild)
                x->parent->lchild = y;
        else
                x->parent->rchild = y;

            y->rchild = x;
            x->parent = y;

}
```

**RBnode.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include"RBnode.h"
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

RBnode::RBnode(){

        int colorData = 1 ;
        parent = NULL;
        lchild = NULL;
        rchild = NULL;
        data = -1;

}
RBnode::~RBnode(){

}
// Assign a color to a node
void RBnode::changeColor(int color){
    this->colorData = color;


}
// Assign data to a node
void RBnode::changeData( int data ){
    this->data = data;
}
```

**RBnode.h**

```
#ifndef RBNODE_H_
#define RBNODE_H_

#include<iostream>
// create reb black node structure
class RBnode{
public:
    RBnode();
    ~RBnode();
    RBnode * parent;
    RBnode * lchild;
    RBnode * rchild;
    int colorData;
        int data;

    void changeColor(int color);
    void changeData(int data);
};



#endif
```

**RBTree.h**

```
#ifndef RBTREE_H_
#define RBTREE_H_
#include<string>
#include <list>
#include<iostream>
#include"RBnode.h"

using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using namespace std;
// prototype functions
class RBtree{
public:
    RBtree();
    ~RBtree();
    void RBwrite(RBnode* tempRoot, FILE * fd);  
    RBnode* RBinsert(int);
    RBnode* RBinsert(int color, int data);
    void RBinstertFixup(RBnode*);
    void Lrotate(RBnode* x);
    void Rrotate(RBnode* x);
    RBnode* getRoot();

private:
    RBnode* nil;
    RBnode* root;   
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "RBTree.h"
#include "RBnode.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

size_t n;
uint32_t data;
RBtree* RB;
bool tree = false;





int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
//declare file pointer
FILE * fs;
FILE * fd;

// init vars here
int n,c;
RBtree* RB = new RBtree();


if (argc < 2){
    printf("ERROR: include the name of the input file as an argument\n");
    return 0;
    }

printf("Attempting to open file %s\n", argv[1]);
char *input = argv[1];
std::ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open(input);
if(inputfile.fail())  // Error check for file
    {
    std::cout << "The file could not be opened!\n";
    return 0;
    }else{ printf("\nFile opened succesfully!");}
    //begin aquistion of data

fs = fopen(input,"r");
fd = fopen("output.txt","w");
fscanf(fs,"%d",&n);
int color, val;
// Insert existing N number of elements
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

    fscanf(fs,"%d %d", &color, &val);

    RB->RBinsert(color, val);

    }

// Insert C number of elements.
fscanf(fs,"%d", &c);
int temp;
for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){

    fscanf(fs,"%d",&temp);
    if(temp != 0){
    RB->RBinstertFixup(RB->RBinsert(temp));
    RB->RBwrite(RB->getRoot(),fd);
    fprintf(fd,"\n\n");
    }


    }

// close files and print status to console
fclose(fd);
fclose(fs);
printf("\nProgram finished!");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: note, in the posted code I put lchild where it should be rchild somewhere in the right rotate. I was just playing around to see what would happen. Even when that is right, I get errors.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. With this code, I get the professor's results.

Comment: Are you sure? I just retried it, same errors. It matches her output up to a certain point only. then changes.

Comment: lol! Just fixed it. Found another thread with slightly different code but a similar error. In my insert fix up there were two if statements that were meant to be else if.